# Why email js not sending mail when using from react app?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, email

Email js is not sending any email when i am sending from my react app contact us page , though email is working fine when i am testing it from the website itself . here is the code for email js i have used. I have removed the unncessary part.

```
function Contactme() {
  const form = useRef();
  function sendEmail(e){
    emailjs.sendForm('gmail', 'template_ppq****', form.current, 'iWxx2qNPr0xxu****')
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
    });
    e.target.reset();
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="contact-box">
        <div className="details">
          <h2>Contact</h2>
          <p>Fill up the form to contact</p>
        </div>
        <div className="sendmsg">
          <form action="" onSubmit={sendEmail} ref={form}>
          <div className="contact-right name-input" name="name">
          Your Name
          <input type="text" className="contact-right-input email-input" name="from_name" />
          Your email
          <input type="text" className="contact-right-input message-input" name="email"/>
          Subject
          <input type="text" className="contact-right-input message-input" name="subject"/>
          Your message
          <textarea id="" cols="30" rows="10" style={{border:"1px solid lightblue"}} name="message"></textarea>
          <button className="contact-btn" >Submit</button>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: This is the syntax of the email]

Comment: did you solve it? as I'm facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to your input field and ensure the ID is the same with the set up on your Emailjs dashboard. I hope  this helps

Comment: That's what worked for me ! Forget to match id/name of inputs & emailJS, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. At emailjs.sendForm('gmail'..........  instead of 'gmail' use your service ID[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol4o5.png)

Answer (score 0):

If adding an ID did not work for you, and a name element and make sure it matches the names you added in the emailJs template, like so;

```
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"

          // this
          name="email"

          placeholder=" Your email"
          required
        />
```

For a more detailed explanation [check this](https://medium.com/geekculture/emailjs-how-to-connect-a-multiple-step-react-form-to-emailjs-a183699e7d3d)